# WPF XAML Move/reposition a point in a Path using Storyboard

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, path, storyboard

So I have a project where I am making a list of items that can be expanded to reveal additional information. So far I have come up with a way to rotate the angles 180 degrees to indicate if the information panel is open or closed, but I feel it looks a little bit artificial.
[Gif demonstration here.](http://g.recordit.co/NAd1IUq200.gif) Ideally, I would like my angle (<) to morph into pointing the opposite way. So let's say the coordinates are -5,0 0,5 and 5,0 (Red) I would like to animate them going to -5,5 0,0 and 5,5 (Blue).
[image]

I have been googling about this for a while, using keywords like animation / path / morph / storyboard. My theory now is that there could be a way where you could name each point in the Path data individually and add styles to them where they will move positions based on a common data trigger. Currently, it's all connected like shown below, and it's all linked up to a style that is attached to the Path. I would prefer to do all of this in XAML, so any help is appreciated.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RevealAdditionalInformation}" Value="False">
  <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ArrowPointUp"/>
    <BeginStoryboard Name="ArrowPointDown">
      <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(LayoutTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)" From="180" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.6"/>
      </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
  </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

---

**Update**:

I've been trying to find a new way to draw up my Path rather than just 
`<Path Data="m 0 0 5 5 5 -5">`. So now I have the same shape written in a different way.  Perhaps this would be easier to manipulate each point separately. What's problematic here is that I am not allowed to name any of these points with `Name="Something"`, so they will be hard to access.

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Grid.Column="1">
  <Path.Data>
    <PathGeometry>
      <PathGeometry.Figures>
        <PathFigureCollection>
          <PathFigure IsClosed="False" StartPoint="0,0">
            <PathFigure.Segments>
              <PathSegmentCollection>
                <LineSegment Point="5,5" />
                  <LineSegment Point="10,0" />
                </PathSegmentCollection>
              </PathFigure.Segments>
            </PathFigure>
          </PathFigureCollection>
        </PathGeometry.Figures>
      </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
  </Path>
```

**Update 2**:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RevealAdditionalInformation}" Value="True">
  <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <BeginStoryboard Name="AnimateTrue">
      <Storyboard>
        <PointAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Figures">
          <PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="m -5 0 0 5 5 0"/>
          </PointAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
        </PointAnimationUsingPath>
      </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
  </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

This is another take I've been experimenting with, the problem here seems to be The Storyboard.Target property, not perhaps a different sort of Animation is needed. The path I am experimenting with this on is this, where `FiguresTest` is the Style that uses the above Data Trigger.

```
<Path x:Name="_testPath" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Style="{StaticResource FiguresTest}">
  <Path.Data>
    <PathGeometry Figures="m -5 5 0 0 5 5"/>
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: You could animate the X or Y value of a ScaleTransform from 1 to -1.

Comment: I actually did try that, but it didn't seem to work. Perhaps I had the syntax wrong. I'll look more into that! I was using <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(LayoutTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" From="-1" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.6"/>

Comment: The parenthesis around LayoutTransform are wrong. Try `Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform‌​.ScaleY)"` or just `Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.ScaleY"`

Comment: Actually, what I was missing was a blank ScaleTransform on the Path itself, I just remembered had I to do that to make the rotation work too. It doesn't automatically add one in the Storyboard. So now it sort of works: http://g.recordit.co/Jyuny4mfrM.gif  But it's not 100% what I wanted tho, but it's definitely an upgrade from the first example I posted. Yet I feel like this is a rotation too, just on another axis, and not really a morph, or manipulation of the actual shape.

Comment: The problem with using `ScaleTransform` is that while both extremes (1 and -1) work well, all the intermediate states not so much - the chevron is distorted ("squeezed") vertically, and disappears completely in the middle state (when `ScaleY` is 0).

Comment: Yeah that's what I was experiencing @Grx70 But it was way better than my initial attempt at rotating around the Z axis. Didn't look intuitive at all, still think your suggestion underneath will be exactly what I wanted. Allthough credit to Clemens for showing me a better solution than what I already had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate individual points on the `Path`. In order to do that, you need to define your `Path` in a manner in which each point you want to animate is a property of a named element. This of course results in more verbose definition, but gets you what you're after. For example:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure x:Name="Figure" StartPoint="-5,5">
                <LineSegment x:Name="Line1" Point="0,0" />
                <LineSegment x:Name="Line2" Point="5,5" />
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Then the animation could look like this:

```
<BeginStoryboard Name="AnimateTrue">
    <Storyboard>
        <PointAnimation To="-5,0" Duration="0:0:0.5"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Figure"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="StartPoint" />
        <PointAnimation To="0,5" Duration="0:0:0.5"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Line1"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point" />
        <PointAnimation To="5,0" Duration="0:0:0.5"
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Line2"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point" />
    </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

---

**EDIT**

Since you're struggling with getting things working, below is an example in which the `Path` is part of `ToggleButton` template. It seems to be a good choice given it will be used to toggle expansion state.

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Duration x:Key="AnimationDuration">0:0:0.2</Duration>
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Border Background="Transparent">
                <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Width="10" Height="5">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathFigure x:Name="Figure" StartPoint="0,0">
                                <LineSegment x:Name="Line1" Point="5,5" />
                                <LineSegment x:Name="Line2" Point="10,0" />
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="ToggleOn">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <PointAnimation To="0,5" Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Figure"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="StartPoint" />
                                <PointAnimation To="5,0" Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Line1"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point" />
                                <PointAnimation To="10,5" Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Line2"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="ToggleOff">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <PointAnimation Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Figure"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="StartPoint" />
                                <PointAnimation Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Line1"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point" />
                                <PointAnimation Duration="{StaticResource AnimationDuration}"
                                                Storyboard.TargetName="Line2"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
</ToggleButton>
```

Note that the animations are triggered only by `ToggleButton.IsChecked` property (as opposed to data triggers bound to view-model properties), so this control is potentially reusable (I suggest you move the template to a style first though). The only thing to do is to properly bind the `ToggleButton.IsChecked` property.

Comment: I will try this first thing in the morning. Cheers a lot, it was something like this I was hoping to achieve, but couldn't figure out how to do. Any ideas as to how demanding this will be in regard to processing power compared to the Y-axis flip?

Comment: I don't really know the difference in complexity between these two, but I'd expect this one to be at least as "easy" as the scale approach. Mainly because what it takes is to simply translate three points (and render two lines), whereas with scale, if I'm not mistaken, the path is rendered (but not yet displayed) first, and only then the transform matrix is applied to each individual point of the rendered image (which seems like a lot more work). And even if scale works cleverly, it still needs to translate these points (and recalculate thickness), so there's at least as much work to be done.

Comment: Struggling a tad now with this, "TargetName property cannot be set on a Style Setter". So trying to find a workaround for this.

Comment: Been trying to implement this directly into the Path.Triggers too, still won't let me do it. I think perhaps I have to go through VisualStates. Gonna have a go at that now.